The "Create a custom filter" link does not work when you are viewing filtered questions
When you're viewing custom filtered questions (for example, I have used this) you can't create a new filter.
Steps to reproduce:

Create a new filter. Anything would suffice.
Go to the page with new filter (it should redirect you automatically).
Click the "Create a custom filter" link:




Nothing happens.

I was reproducing this in incognito mode so it's not caused by extensions or userscripts.
There were no errors in console other than some ads and warnings.
